# What is the closure of $S^1\times \mathbb{Z}$ in Homeo$(S^2\times \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions

Let $X = S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ and $G=S^1\times \mathbb{Z}$. Let $G$ act on $X$ as follows - $S^1$ acts on $S^2$ by rotation leaving the north and south poles fixed and acts trivially on $\mathbb{R}$. The generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ reflects $S^2$ about the equator and translates $\mathbb{R}$ along one unit.

I have two questions -

1. What does this action do to $X$? More precisely, what is $X/G$?

I can see that the orbit space of the $S^1$ action on $S^2$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$ and the orbit space of $\mathbb{Z}$ action on $\mathbb{R}$ is the circle, but this reflection about equator confuses me.  Can I visualize this action by breaking it up like I did or am I going about it wrong? Is there an explicit expression for this action? That is, what would be the image of $(x,r)\in X$ be under $(z,n) \in G$?

2. What is $\bar{G}$, the closure of $G$ in Homeo$(X)$ with the [compact open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology)?

I thought I could show $G$ is closed in Homeo$(X)$ using nets. However since I haven't understood what the action does to $X$ I am having trouble starting this one.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to write elements of $S^2 \times \Bbb R$ in cylindrical coordinates: $((\theta,z),t)$. Then $(n,\phi) \cdot ((\theta,z),t) = ((\phi+\theta,(-1)^n z),t+n)$. It may be easiest to think this way. The quotient $X/G$, I think, is a compact Mobius strip. (First think of what the $S^1$ action does then what the $\Bbb Z$ action does to $S^2/S^1$. One should take more care than I am here but this should give a proof.) I also think $G$ is closed but have not been very careful about it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the projection $X \to \hat{X} = X/S^1$ (we quantify by the action of $S^1 \times \{0\} \subset G$).
One can translate the action of $\mathbb Z$ onto $\hat{X}$: $$k\cdot p(x):= p(k\cdot x)$$ (get sure, that this is correct!). But $\hat{X}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$.Let's denote the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the $\hat{X}$ in the coordinates: $$1\cdot(x, t) = (x+1, 1-t)$$
Consider then a square $[0;1]\times[0;1]$ and a map $v$ from the square to itself: $(y, s) \mapsto (y+1\mod(1), 1-s)$. It is well known, that the result of gluing on $v$ is the M$\ddot o$bius strip. 
But the action of 1 on $\hat{X}$ is just a periodic extending of map $v$ on the whole tape.

It might be not as precise as you wish, but I hope, the idea is clear.